# Como setar o menu do Navigation View por código?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, navigation-drawer

Por enquanto eu estou setando o menu através do xml, dessa maneira:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroud"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav">
```

Porem eu quero antes de setar o menu fazer uma verificação com if, para isso eu precisaria setar ele por código, por exemplo... se(if) usuário fosse igual a "administrador" abrisse um menu diferente do de "usuarios".

segue meu código por enquanto:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Como eu faço para setar o menu do navigationview por código?

Comment: Você está criando um do zero ou está usando o Layout gerado pelo próprio Android Studio? Eu sugiro que você crie uma nova Activity do tipo Navigation Menu. Automaticamente será gerado o código e o Layout que chama esse menu. Sendo assim, você faria um segundo Layout e validaria o usuário, dependendo da sua validação infla o layout do usuário se não infla o layout do Admin.

Comment: Já vi algumas formas de fazer isso sem precisar fazer um layout, e na verdade é exatamente isso q estou procurando, como eu faço para setar somente o menu diferente e não o layout.

Comment: Mesmo se você puder criar usando o mesmo, acredito que não valeria a pena pois teria que validar também os campos que aparecerão para um e para outro.

Comment: Eu pensei em só trocar qual arquivo menu eu vou usar dependendo do usuario, por exemplo. Se fosse administrador - menu_nav_adm.xml e se fosse usuario normal - menu_nav_usuarios.xml

Comment: Exatamente, era isso que eu tentei dizer no primeiro comentário, acabei me expressando mal hehe, mas a ideia é essa mesmo.

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui, fui dar uma olhada na doc e consegui. Utilizei o if normalmente e se fosse verdadeiro ele inflava um tipo de menu. Código utilizado:                     navigationView.getMenu().clear();
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav);

Comment: Se quiser escrever uma resposta pra eu aceitar aceitar ela, pode fazer!

Comment: Show, coloca o trecho da solução como resposta, fica mais claro e objetivo desta forma. =)